# Resource shrinker cannot be used for multi-apk applications

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-r8, dynamic-feature-module

So today I decided to try my hand at making at making a dynamic feature module. I have R8 enabled with both minifyEnabled and shrinkResources set to true. Trying to compile gives me the following error.

```
Resource shrinker cannot be used for multi-apk applications
Affected Modules: app
```

Has anyone else seen this? There are similar questions around stack but nothing directly related to DFMs.

I would love to keep this flag enabled to avoid library bloat

Gradle Plugin: 4.0.0

Gradle Wrapper: 6.1.1

Answer (score 5):

This feature is implemented starting Android Gradle Plugin 4.2.0 and can be enabled by setting `android.experimental.enableNewResourceShrinker=true` flag in gradle properties.

Details are available [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120517460).